# Evaluating Custom Directive after jQuery replaceWith

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AngularCtrl">
  <a href="#" id="click_btn">Click here</a>
</div>
<script>
 jQuery("#click_btn").click(function(){
  jQuery(this).replaceWith('<p>Hello {{student.name}}</p><div my-repeater></div>');
 });
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is my angular code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myRepeater', function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',        
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var myTemplate = "<div>{{rating}}</div>";
        for(var i=0;i<scope.items.length;i++)
        {
            var myItem = scope.items[i];                    
            var text = myTemplate.replace("{{rating}}",myItem.rating);
            element.append(text);
        }
    }
 };
}); 

function AngularCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.student = {id: 1, name: 'John'};
  $scope.items = [{id: 1, ratings: 10}, {id: 2, ratings: 20}];
}
```

Here, whenever i click on the button, the element is just getting replaced and not evaluated. I tried with "angular.bootstrap(document);" after document is ready.

But that just evaluates the angular objects. But still the custom directive "my-repeater" is not getting evaluated. Any help on how can i get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suppose this is test code, since angular has [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat), which fits your needs.

There are several issues with your code:

1) You shouldn't use **myTemplate.replace**, but use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service. Inject the $compile service into your directive (add as function param) and use it:

```
var text = $compile(myTemplate)(scope);
```

2) Items on the controller will not by accessible in your directive. Add it as a value to your my-repeater attribute:

```
<div my-repeater='{{items}}'>
```

In your directive you need to evaluate my-repeater:

```
var items = scope.$eval(attrs.myRepeater);
```

3) **jQuery(this).replaceWith** will not kickoff angular, since it it out of its scope. You need to do it manually by using [scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply).  But is better to add the click event in the directive link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function() {   
           ...
           scope.$apply();
        });
```

Edit: Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/cAkCx/).

Comment: I have created JS Fiddle of the same. http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/br6e2/1/ .Here after replacing, the angular objects are not evaluated.

Comment: Thanks Very much asgoth! But in my scenario, where i use rails, I want to replace with a big html partial containing elements with many angular directives and bindings combined with some rails stuffs. so I will have to use jQuery(this).replaceWith. The issue is why the custom directive binding is not happening when we say **angular.bootstrap(document)**. Will bootstrap only evaluate and not take care of custom bindings and watches?

Comment: My problem is how can i evaluate the custom directive? Can you please help me with this? When i do **angular.bootstrap(document)** all the ng- directives are evaluated but not the custom directives. Can you please help me with how i can get the custom directive evaluated?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. I've updated the example. It had some bugs too, which I removed.